# Using friendly URLs for web pages and Rest Styles URLs for services, is it a good approach?

Tags: seo, url, restful

Is my approach to SEO regarding URLs right?

I am using friendly URLs for web pages and Rest Styles to consume services. I've been a web developer for about 10 years. I first heard of "friendly URLs" and Rest APIs about 3 years ago and only about 1 year ago I started implementing some of those concepts.

In my last project I used URLs like this for web pages `www.example.com/enter` to show to login page as opposed to `www.example.com/login/show`. And to consume services like a searching API that returns JSON, I used something like this `www.example.com/produtos/get`. Those are only examples. I saw some Microsoft web sites using Rest style URLs some time ago and I thought them very weird, like `www.example.com/user/create` on the browser's URL bar. Again, I think that friendly URLs should be used for indexing while Rest Style urls should be "hidden" and used to specify the route to be consumed.

Is my line of thinking good?

Comment: As far as SEO is concerned, as long as you can make your URLs friendly then you are done. You can use the technology you like. You may need to consider things like: Duplicate content issue, canonical, future planning if URLs may change then having proper 301 etc.

Comment: Yes, thinking about it, rest style Urls are friendly to search engines. I think they are very robotic. Maybe I shouldn't consider only my opnion.

Comment: I'm not sure why your URLs would have "show" or "get" in them.  Those action words are implied.  This guide for restful URLs doesn't use such action words for displaying content: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html   I can see the case for "create" because that differentiates it from displaying a user or a list of users.

Comment: I wouldn't use either `/enter` or `/login/show`.   I would just use `/login`.     No sites call the login process "enter", and the "show" is just not needed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, yes, a better example of Rest Url to show content would be www.example.com/products/4321 or www.example.com/products/4321/red-large-product-aluminum. But the same way, it is very robotic in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, even from UX point of view, descriptive URLs for web pages are better. It will also have the SEO benefit you require.